# Does every operation contain a chest?

Tags: the-division

After playing through a lot of operations in the underground we've noticed that a few of them have a chest or two scattered.

I'm not talking about the odd backpack or bag but a big honking green army chest, with yellow or green items inside.

The question is, does every operation contain one of these and we've just been lousy at finding them or is this part of the randomness of the underground?

Comment: http://www.gosunoob.com/division/secret-chest-locations-in-missions/ I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

In the Underground its random.
As soon as you enter the Underground you get random Tile Sets that get pieced together.

Some of these Tiles have set chest locations on them.

Once you learn them you should always check them, since that is the only position where extra loot can drop in the Underground